# SharePoint Online, Infopath 2013 - Hide admin view from requester in Infopath

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, permissions, list-view

I have a Infopath form (Request form) added to a SharePoint list. I have two views to the infopath form, One is default Edit view and the other is Admin view. So the users, when they select new item through link provided on a Sitepage, should only see the Default Edit view (Not Admin view). And When they fill this request form, they should only see List items created by them [My View].

But my team as admins should be able to access Admin view of Infopath and also the All Items view on the list.

I tried adding special permission level by unchecking Manage views and list items action. I was successfull in hiding edit item and delete item [in the toolbar] from the users, but they are still able to see Admin View in Infopath and All Items view on associated SharePoint list.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Create a form load rule that checks to see if the user is an admin or not, and switch views depending on that condition. For example if current user not admin, switch to Edit view.

Comment: I would create another list in your sharepoint site, with a person field and call it like Admins or whatever. Add everyone who is an admin to this list, and create a data connection to this list in Infopath. For your condition on form load check to see if current user ID is equal to any of the user IDs in your Admin List.

Comment: It did not work. I did try as explained. I can still see admin view on the navigation when logged with User account(Non admin account). If i hide the admin view from the property window in infopath, I (Admin) cannot access the Admin view of this form when i go to edit item (created by the user).

Comment: You should remove the ability to switch views from the toolbar. And add a button on the admin view of your form to switch. So that way admins have ability to switch views, but non-admins don't.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, How do i achieve this. If i go to Page Design > Admin View > Properties > General > I see three options, Set as default value, Show on the view menu when filling out this form and Read only. I see if i uncheck Show on the view menu, I can hide it. But how do the admin access the form (Going to list and selecting this item), edit it and they can view the Admin view. Can you please be more specific. I will be very thankful with your assistance.

Comment: On your form load, create a rule that checks to see if current user is an Admin or not. If they are admin have the form switch to Admin view. That way when admin opens the form they see admin view, and regular people see the standard view.

Comment: I did the same, as you explained and it din work. I created a list, added admins to list, set data connection, Added rule to the form load to switch views. But it din work. I have a field full name in my infopath which is a data connection that pulls account id of the current user. In the Form load condition i added Full Name - AccountId is equal to Account Id [Secondary data connection to Admin list].

Comment: Is the account ID in your form in the same format as the one in your list?

Comment: Yes it is. I finally achieved this by adding form load condition like Full Name is equal to Add Text [Name of Admin]. This works out if the Admin list is Short.  If the Admin group is big, try http://www.hishamqaddomi.ca/spg/index.php/sharepoint-2010/infopath-2010/65-checking-if-a-user-is-a-member-in-a-sharepoint-group-within-web-infopath-2010-forms